# How can I access docker database Remotly?

Tags: laravel, docker

I have one project on a server which is in laravel 4.1 with docker and I have to access it remotly on different server in laravel lumen project. How can I do this?

I have tried by giving hostname as IP address of our server and by giving username and password of db. I have also tried by giving IP access in mysql db. But none is working. I have added following configuration values in .env file:-

```
'MYSQL_HOST' => '<IP>',
'MYSQL_DATABASE' => '<DATABASE>',
'MYSQL_USER' => '<USER>',
'MYSQL_PASSWORD' => '<PASSWORD>',
```

Thanks

Comment: the container with the database should expose its port (so it will be accessible from outside of docker), then from the other server you do as if you were not using docker at all, use ip and port of the first server (maybe you have a firewall to configure too, you haven't told us much of your setup)

Comment: Detail `docker-compose.yml` please so people could help you not just guess what happen to you.

Comment: I have added ip and port ('MYSQL_HOST' => '<ip>:<port>'). But its not working